# Uninstall OSXVnc under Mac OS X Leopard

Tags: mac, mac-osx, vnc

I used to have need for OSXVNC ([now Vine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/)), but with Mac OSX Leopard, I'm quite happy with the built-in VNC support.

I just am wondering how I go about uninstall this thing though.  When I fire up Console app, I see OSXVNC is maintaining a log, so I assume a Daemon's running.  This should be easy picking's for all Mac sysadmins.

Answer (score 4):

It should be a simple matter of opening `Vine Server.app` in `/Applications`, going into the Server, System Server menu, and clicking "Stop System Server".

If this doesn't work, navigate to `/Library/LaunchAgents` and look for `com.redstonesoftware.VineServer.plist` or anything else starting with `com.redstonesoftware`. Delete any files you find that look like Vine/OSXVNC and then restart the Mac.

After the launch agent has been removed, you can delete the application bundle from /Applications should you wish.

Comment: in addition to Jason's answer, you might want to take a look at AppZapper: http://www.appzapper.com